# Angular 7 Type 'Observable<{ main: HttpResponse<any>; size: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Order[]>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service

hey i have upgraded my angular 4.4 to latest latest 7
now i got my services to work now i am getting this error which i did not before

Type 'Observable<{ main: HttpResponse; size: any; }>' is not assignable to type Observable< Order[] >

i am getting null response

any idea why this error is occuring

**services**

```js
getReports(
    searchCriteria: SearchCriteria,
    physicianId?: number,
    locationId?: number | string
    ): Observable<Order[]> {

    let findUrl: string = "/encounters/reported";

    let queryObject: any = {
      sort: searchCriteria.Sort,
      order: searchCriteria.Order,
      q: searchCriteria.SearchTerm,
      page: searchCriteria.PageNumber
    };

    if (Boolean(locationId)) {
      queryObject.locationId = locationId;
    } else if (Boolean(physicianId)) {
      queryObject.physicianId = physicianId;
    }

    let queryParams = this.utilService.setQueryParams(queryObject);

    return this.http.get(findUrl, { params: queryParams }).pipe(
      map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        const reportSize: any = res.headers.get("total");
        return (
          { main: res, size: reportSize }
        );
      }),
      catchError(this.utilService.handleError),);
}
```

**ts file**

```js
public ordersData :any
public totalReportsCount :any

getReportsDetail() {
    this.patientService
      .getReports(this.searchCriteria, this.user.DoctorId, null)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data,'data')
        this.ordersData = data.main;
        this.totalReportsCount = data.size;
      });
}
```

can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: Where is that error come from ? Please take a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message is because your service functions tries to return an object with a different type than the one expected. *However the error shouldn't affect the request content itself, it's more like type safety.*

- To get rid of the error either change the type your returning as an
  object of type `{var: HttpResponse, var2: any}`
- Or return only the response body (`res.body`), which I presume
  represents an `Order` array, to fit the: `getReports(...): Observable<Order[]>`

That being said, you might wanna throw a little `console.log(res)` in your `map()` to see if there's actually any content arriving from your request.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an object that TypeScript can infer it as of an `Order` object, but you're explicitly stating that the function should return an *array* of `Order` objects.

To put it simply,

```
{ main: res, size: reportSize } instanceof Array // returns false
[{ main: res, size: reportSize }] instanceof Array // returns true
```

Simply change your returned object in brackets and it will work.

```
return (
  [{ main: res, size: reportSize }]
);
```